# Php with wrong json response on ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i'm not a php developer, i'm doing this to help a friend. I have an issue with my ajax response from my php file. In my HTML i make an ajax request

```js
function addNewBrand() {
    disableAllButton();

    var excludeBrandOnFacebook = $('#facebook_brand_excluded').is(":checked");
    var excludeBrandOnTrovaprezzi = $('#trovaprezzi_brand_excluded').is(":checked");

    if(excludeBrandOnFacebook || excludeBrandOnTrovaprezzi) {
        var outOfStockArray = getOutOfStockValueArray();
        var categories = getExcludedCategory();

        var newBrand = getNewBrandToExclude();
        var brands = getExcludedBrand();
        brands.push(newBrand);

        var obj = { excludeOutOfStock: outOfStockArray, brands: brands, categories: categories};
        var rulesJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);

        console.log(rulesJSON);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/save_rules.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: rulesJSON,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {

                if(data.status == 'success'){
                    appendRow(newBrand);
                    alert("Complete!");
                    $( '#brand_to_append').val('');
                    $( '#trovaprezzi_brand_excluded' ).prop('checked', false);
                    $( '#facebook_brand_excluded' ).prop('checked', false);
                } else if(data.status == 'error'){
                    alert("An error occours! " + data.msg);
                }

                enableAllButton();
            },
            error: function( result ) {
                console.log(result);
                alert("Ops, something went wrong. " + result.msg);
                enableAllButton();
            }
        });
    } else {
        enableAllButton();
    }
}
```

And process it in my save_rules.php in this way

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php 
    if( session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ){ 
        session_start();
    }

    //require platform core files
    require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-load.php");
    require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-includes/pluggable.php");
    //include(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php");
    ini_set("memory_limit", '2048M');

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $rawdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    // Let's say we got JSON
    $decoded = json_decode($rawdata);

    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/rules.json";
    $jsonFile = fopen( $file, "w+" );
    fwrite($jsonFile, $rawdata);
    fclose($jsonFile);

    $post_array = array();

    if( $rawdata != null ) {
        $post_array[] = ['code'=>200, 'status'=>'success'];
    } else {
        $post_array[] = ['code'=>400, 'status'=>'error'];
    }

    echo json_decode( $post_array );

?>
```

Until few days ago everythings works but now i got an error. Actually i receive a 200 status code response but in my js function error section is fired instead of success. The problem, i think, is on my JSON response. I checked on chrome console and i get this from server

```
#!/usr/bin/php
{"code":200,"status":"success"}
```

Why this happen? And why this not happens until few days ago? All your answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the first line in your php file.

Comment: Did you check the actual return string? Is it still valid JSON. Sometimes the strings get cut off.

Comment: @RST how can i check the return string?

Comment: @fredrik I'm going to try to remove the first line. But just to know, is not necessary the first line in a php file?

Comment: print_r() or var_dump() $rawdata before decoding command?

Comment: That 200 is not the status code, it's basically a number you've typed in your code. The status code isn't rendered to browser, you need to check it in e.g. the *Network* pane. In any case, you aren't doing any error checking beyond `$rawdata`.

Comment: You need that first file if you are going to run the script in a shell on the computer, not when it's a website running inside a webserver.

Comment: Thanks to all, removing the first line worked for me. @Alvaro i know that 200 is not a status code, it was only a rapid check for me in my html page but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was in your save_rules.php file here :

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
```

In fact when you load this file it output firt the string "**#!/usr/bin/php**" and after play the PHP code. So you response are not JSON valid because before your JSON you got the string "**#!/usr/bin/php**".

So remove this string from your PHP code and your JSON will be OK.

One more thing at the end of your PHP file use :

```
echo json_encode( $post_array );
```

Because you want to send JSON right ? Not a decoded JSON.

Comment: @Ibbanez thanks you can makr the solution is valide for the problem, up vote appreciate too